# What is the motivation for studying this subgroup of $SL_n(\Bbb R)?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, determinant, big-picture

Consider a diagonal matrix $A$ with entries $e^{s_1},e^{s_2},\cdot\cdot\cdot$ on the diagonal s.t. $\sum_{i \ge1} s_i=0.$ From what I understand this is a subgroup of $SL_n(\Bbb R).$ This is because the determinant of a diagonal matrix is the product of the diagonal entries, and when we do this computation we get that the determinant equals $1$. The special linear group is the space of matrices with determinant $1$.

> Does $A$ have a name? What is the motivation for studying this subgroup of $SL_n(\Bbb R)?$

Comment: Yes, it is called "a maximal split torus." The structure theory of semisimple Lie groups and their representation theory is built around studying a maximal torus and its normalizer, in this case, the group of upper triangular matrices  (leading to the Weyl group). It is a very long story, takes a book to explain.

Comment: To clarify the comment of Moishe, the upper triangular matrices are not the normalizer of this subgroup, but rather enter the picture in a different way, being a Borel subgroup.